# SharePoint Custom Form

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, powerapp, forms-7

I have a requirement to design a checklist form in SharePoint which needs to look like this. 
[image: Form]
I am allowed to use SharePoint Designer or PowerApps ( NO Infopath ) any pointers on how to achieve this.

What will be the best approach to achieve this? Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That can be done with PowerApps. Either create a custom list form or create a standalone app that stores its data in the SharePoint Online list. If the questions are yes/no questions, PowerApps will show a slider that you can set to yes or no.

You won't be able to have such a harsh layout table in PowerApps, unless you enjoy setting properties of all the labels and the rows manually, which is quite time consuming.

But it can be done.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply, any pointers (blogs or forms) will be very useful and helpful. Thanks again :)

Comment: Really? You can't google Powerapps yourself?